# If wattage becomes insufficient on USB Hub, does bandwidth begin to decrease or devices just fail?

Tags: usb-hub

Consider a 60-watt USB 3.0, 7-port, Hub with 2 (12-watt) *Fast Charge* ports.

- `HooToo USB 3.0 7 port + 2 "fast charging" ports (HT-UH010)` = **60-watt adapter**;
- (USB 3.0 port at 5-watts) * 7 ports = 35-watts;
- (12-watt "charging only" port) * 2 = 24-watts;
- 35 + 24 = **59-watts worst case consumption**;

I'm sure that *x*% of the time, each port can be *y*% over/under their wattage specs. Because of that variability, if I end-up needing more than 60-watts:

- is there expected behavior on a MacBook with 2 * (USB 3.0) ports? One onboard port will have a `Diamond USB HDMI/DVI Display Adapter`. The other will have this hub with a few hdd attached.
- if there ever is trouble with devices (mostly hdd) attached to hub, I can just unplug whatever from the *Fast Charge* ports. This frees-up 24-watts, and so eliminates wattage as possible cause of device failures?
- will I/O bandwidth improve if I don't use the *Fast Charge* ports and just wall charge?

disclaimer: I've no background in electronics and just did a lot of googling for these calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should happen is the following:
1) Your hub has at least 100mwatt power for each USB port.
2) Each device may then request more power (up to five times as much).

This extra power may be approved **or it may be denied**. (E.g. when the hub has insufficient power. If it is denied then the device will probably not function at all.

Basically, it is a 'it works at the start' or 'it does not work at all'.

Three notes:
1) This depends on well behaved USB devices (including the hub).
2) For USB 3.0 the power levels are different (e.g. 150mWatt per bin)
3) Fast charging is getting introduced with USB 3.1. I am not aware of any standards before that. (mind you I set standards. Some implementations are ahead of well defined standards and there is no way to tell how they behave).

For you this basically means that watteage should not be able to become unsufficient. PLug in extra stuff and the extra stuff simply does not start. The already present equipment keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when numerous devices exceed the power provided by the USB hub, devices will stop functioning. How and when are entirely up to the hub's hardware. Just the other day I had this very issue. I plugged in a USB flash drive into a hub, which must have been right on the cusp of its ability to provide power. This causes a USB flash drive on the hub to go unpowered.

Bandwidth will not decrease as the power and bandwidth are provided on different wires of a USB device.